# Grep for a pattern using current visual selection on another file

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

I want to basically search for a pattern in the current file on another file, from vim, using the current visual selection.

I know doing:

```
:grep pattern otherfile
```

works, but i want the 'pattern' to be the current visual selection instead (from the current opened file)

How could i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thought that occurs to me: yank the text (`y`), and then paste it at the `:grep` command:

```
:grep <C-r>" ...
```

Note that this doesn't work too well for multi-line selections, and you may want something more like

```
<C-r>=escape(@", '/\')<CR>
```

to handle some escape sequences.

---

I'm making use of the "insert register" keystroke (`:help <C-r>`) and the fact that registers can be used as expressions when prefixed with `@`.

Comment: how do i add support for more escape sequences to the second method? (like for example, to escape the character '#' so that it look like '\#')

Comment: You can add more characters to the second argument of escape()

Comment: you're right, seems doing it as '\#/\' work :) (don't know if you meant doing it that way though)

Comment: You probably dont need the extra backslash, but yes that’s what I meant.

Comment: one last thing i noticed: seems it add a '^@' at the end of the text that was in the register (only does this for the second method though).

Comment: Hm, looks like a newline. Not sure what’s happening there.